# How do I Merge if key value are the same?

Tags: python, json

roku.json

```
{
"Chicago":{
    "Menu":{
        "Strawberry Pie":[
            {
                "item":"Whipping Cream", 
                "container":"1 oz cup"
            },
            {
                "item":"Water" ,
                "container":"tray 1"  
            },
            {
                "item":"Cornstarch",
                "container":"tray 1"    
            },
            {
                "item":"Sugar",
                "container":"1 oz cup"
            },
            {
                "item":"fresh strawberries",
                "container":"2 oz cup"
            }
    ]
    }
}
}
```

my code

```
import json
with open('roku.json') as file: 
package_json = json.load(file)

menu = package_json['Chicago']['Menu']['Strawberry Pie']    

for i in menu:
    product = i['item']
    container = i['container']
    print(product,container)
```

I was wondering if someone could point to me the right direction how to concatenate if key values are the same.
my current out put is

- Whipping Cream 1 oz cup
- Water tray 1
- Cornstarch tray 1
- Sugar 1 oz cup
- fresh strawberries 2 oz cup

and I want it to be

- Whipping Cream & Sugar 1 oz cup
- Water & Constarch tray 1
- fresh stawberries 2 oz cup

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like you want to create another dictionary that has the value for key `container` as the key and a list of values that are from the key `item` that have the same value from container.  What you should do is traverse through the list creating a new dictionary that in the end would look like:

```
{
  "1 oz cup":["Whipping Cream", "Sugar"],
  "tray 1":["Water", "Cornstarch"],
  "2 oz cup":["fresh strawberries"],
}
```

From this resulting dictionary you can easily go through each key and join the elements in the list together

Comment: I do not wish to create a new dictionary. I want it to be <class 'tuple'>

Comment: That would be the same concept and at the end you can covert the dictionary into many Tuples.  You would have the key as the container and the list of items as the value.